# Communication between PIC18F and Server application Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, assembly

I am working on a project that addresses the communication between PIC18F and VB application server.  I have a little problem between my assembly program and the server application developed in Visual Basic.

My treatment is as follows:

- The server calls my assembly program via a modem connected to the RS232 pc
- After that call, my program picks up the line and open communication
- Then the  server sends the data (via data dtmf function) that I need as well as the acknowledgment of receipt

  - code
  - name
  - last name

My problem is not in the server, it is rather add an accused receiving function in my assembly program, before the server sends data, it must receive the acknowledgment of receipt from my program

Comment: I've expanded what you have to say into paragraphs and lists to make it easier to read and understand.   I'm not sure that you have provided enough information for anybody to help you figure out why the server isn't starting.   Please include any additional information that you might have such as messages from an error log.

Comment: Hello Stephan, thank you very much for your help, in fact ,My problem is not in the server, it is rather add an accused receiving function in my assembly program, before the server sends data, it must receive the acknowledgment of receipt from my program.

Comment: Please edit that information into your question to make your question clear.